# transform and map xml in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to transform the xml request but facing issue while mapping the ID parameter.

for account_work I have to map the id where type will be Revenue_category_id.
for ledger_work I have to map the id where type will be Ledger_category_id.

Please help to get the correct filter logic in the dwl code.

dwl:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Get_Mapping_Tables_Response.Response_Data.Mapping_Table.Mapping_Table_Data.*Rule_Table_Data map {
  "account_work": $.Accounting_working.ID, // need to add filer logic to get Revenue_category_id
  "ledger_work": $.Ledger_working.ID // need to add filer logic to get Ledger_category_id
```

}

Request:

```
 <wd:Get_Mapping_Tables_Response
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsve" wd:version="v40.0">
<wd:Response_Data>
    <wd:Mapping_Table>
        <wd:Mapping_Table_Data>
            <wd:ID>AC_Account_Map</wd:ID>
            <wd:Rule_Table_Data>
                <wd:Accounting_working>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1234</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Revenue_category_id">RC_1</wd:ID>
                </wd:Accounting_working>
                <wd:Ledger_working>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">12345</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Ledger_category_id">LC_1</wd:ID>
                </wd:Ledger_working>
            </wd:Rule_Table_Data>
            <wd:Rule_Table_Data>
                <wd:Accounting_working>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">12346</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Revenue_category_id">RC_2</wd:ID>
                </wd:Accounting_working>
                <wd:Ledger_working>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">12347</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Ledger_category_id1">LC_2</wd:ID>
                </wd:Ledger_working>
            </wd:Rule_Table_Data>
        </wd:Mapping_Table_Data>
    </wd:Mapping_Table>
</wd:Response_Data>
</wd:Get_Mapping_Tables_Response>
```

expected response:

```
      [
        {
          "account_work": "RC_1",
          "ledger_work": "LC_1"
        },
        {
         "account_work": "RC_2",
         "ledger_work": ""
       }
       ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filterObject() with a condition on the `type` attribute of the keys. Non present values return null so I added a default of an empty string to match the expected output.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Get_Mapping_Tables_Response.Response_Data.Mapping_Table.Mapping_Table_Data.*Rule_Table_Data map {
  "account_work": ($.Accounting_working filterObject ((value, key, index) -> key.@`type` == "Revenue_category_id")).ID default "",
  "ledger_work": ($.Ledger_working filterObject ((value, key, index) -> key.@`type` == "Ledger_category_id")).ID  default ""
}
```